# why naked block can not access out scope variable and function if packaged?

Tags: perl

I want to define a class and test with `is` in naked block like this:

```
use Test::More tests => 1;

{
    package Foofle;
    use parent qw(Animal);
    sub sound { 'foof' }

    is(
        Foofle->speak,
        "A Foofle goes foof!\n",
        "An Animal subclass does the right thing"
    );
}
```

I got error `Undefined subroutine &Foofle::is called at t/Animal.t`, so if I add

```
use Test::More;
```

in naked block, then it runs ok.

Or I move `is` outside of naked block,

```
use Test::More tests => 1;

{
    package Foofle;
    use parent qw(Animal);
    sub sound { 'foof' }
}

is(
    Foofle->speak,
    "A Foofle goes foof!\n",
    "An Animal subclass does the right thing"
);
```

it runs ok. But **why naked block can not access out scope variable?**

Comment: I like your example animal. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `use Test::More` call imports the identifier `is` into the current package. In your first implementation, that means importing `is` into the package of your script, which is probably the `main` package. After that, every time you use `is` in the `main` package, Perl knows it should invoke `Test::More::is`.

Now, `is` stops being a synonym of `Test::More::is` as soon as you switch to a different package. In fact, you can try this: call `is()` in your naked block, but *before* you declare `package Foofle`. It should work just fine. It's not the naked block that is to blame; it's the fact that you're now in a different package.

One option is to `use Test::More` in your `Foofle` package as well, as you've tried already. The other is to use your original implementation, but invoke `is` with the fully qualified name: `Test::More::is(Foofle->speak, "...", "...");`.

Answer (score 3):

You are changing the package (or namespace) inside of your block. Each block in Perl creates a *scope*, and you can have scoped `package` changes.

At the beginning of your program, you are in the `main` package. You are `use`ing Test::More in that package, so the `is` function gets *imported* into that package. That means, there is now a `&main::is`, which points to `&Test::More::is`.

Once you switch the package, Test::More has still been loaded, but the `is` function is not imported into the new package. That's why it complains that it cannot find `&Foofle::is`.

**So it's really about the** `package`, **not the block.**

Further reading: [perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Packages) and [`package` in perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/package.html).